# Raster to vector (two attributes per feature)

Tags: qgis, arcmap

I have a raster map of land-use which I want to convert to shapefile. I've used the raster to vector tool from QGis, and I got the polygons for each land-use classes; in the attribute table I got one land-use per polygon and I want to know if there is a way to have two attributes per polygon, the inner and outer land-use (or left and right land-use).

Comment: What do you mean by two attributes? Do you mean two fields (columns), or two rows? One polygon will always have one row, but you can have multiple fields per polygon.

Comment: What do you mean by "inner and outer land-use"?

Comment: I mean columns, I want that each polygon keeps two values ​​from raster data, the value that the polygon is enclosing and also the value of its neighbor polygon @ahmadhanb

Comment: @Erik by inner I mean the value that the polygon is enclosing and by outer the value that the neighbor polygon is enclosing. I'm not sure if polygons can have both values, I've read that you can specify both values using polylines, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcMap but do not say how that software relates to your question in its body.

Comment: @PolyGeo well I have tried with both Softwares QGis and ArcMap in the same way, in ArcMap with Raster to polygon tool